# I made an App using Phonegap + HTML5 + Websql, will the app's data be lost once the user restarts his mobile?

Tags: android, iphone, html, cordova, web-sql

My app uses HTML5's Websql to store temporary notes / bookmarks, which will be synced later with server.

My doubt is - same like the browsers of the phone, will I loose the data in websql upon mobile restart (or cache clear)?

I haven't built the app yet.. Am on the planning part.. and this doubt aroused.. Anybody with experience out there? Coz if websql is volatile, I'll have to hunt for other methods..

EDIT:

Tested myself: Data is safe even mobile is restarted, thanks for your replies..

Comment: Set your data, reboot your phone, check for your data. It takes less time than posting your question here

Comment: I haven't built the app yet.. Am on the planning part.. and this doubt aroused.. Anybody with experience out there? Coz if websql is volatile, I'll have to hunt for other methods..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you will be fine - for iOS be sure to use the latest Cordova - there was an issue at one point with storage but those issues have been resolved as of 1.7.

carry on.